# What is the time complexity of these two solutions?

Tags: python, data-structures, time-complexity

I am solving this problem: Palindromic Substrings.

> Given a string, your task is to count how many palindromic substrings in this string.
>
> The substrings with different start indexes or end indexes are counted as different substrings even they consist of same characters.

I have tried multiple approaches and according to me both these approach have a complexity of **`O(N*3)`**. But leetcode accepts one solution and return time limit exceeded for the other one.

Solution which is accepted:

```
def countSubstrings(self, s):
        count = len(s)
        for i in range(2, len(s)+1):
            j = 0
            while(j < len(s) and j+i <= len(s)):
                t = s[j:j+i]
                j = j + 1
                reverse_t = t[::-1]
                if t == reverse_t:
                    count += 1
        return count
```

Solution for which I get time limit exceeded

```
def countSubstrings(self, s):
        count = len(s)
        for i in range(2, len(s)+1):
            j = 0
            while(j < len(s) and j+i <= len(s)):
                t = s[j:j+i]
                j = j + 1
                reverse_t = ''
                for k in range(len(t)-1, -1, -1):
                    reverse_t += t[k]
                if t == reverse_t:
                    count += 1
        return count
```

The only change in these two algorithm is in one in my using Python `slice` to reverse the string and in the second when I am using a `for` loop. The time complexity for `slice` is **`O(K)`** where `k` is length of slice

Comment: I think this task should be possible without any temporary strings. You will also get a much more simpler and faster algorithm. I could write this algorithm for you but then you wouldn't learn a thing.

Comment: Also your first algorithm doesn't even work. You're adding the number of found palindromes to the length of the input string.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

```
reverse_t = ''
for k in range(len(t)-1, -1, -1):
    reverse_t += t[k]
```

Because strings are immutable, constructing strings by adding 1 letter at a time is horribly inefficient, because on each iteration, you have to construct an entirely new object. Essentially, it's the string concatenation that you didn't account for in your calculation. constructing a string of length n letter by letter is effectively `o(n**2)`

To demonstrate how much of a difference this can make, here is a simple setup:

```
def letter_by_letter_reverse(string):
    reverse_t = ''
    for k in range(len(string)-1, -1, -1):
        reverse_t += string[k]
    return reverse_t

def slice_reverse(string):
    reverse_t = string[::-1]
    return reverse_t

test = 'some_string' * 500

%timeit letter_by_letter_reverse(test)
#1.44 ms ± 204 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit slice_reverse(test)
#8.2 µs ± 56.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```